# add git commit hash to javascript variables during gulp build

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, gulp, fs

I am using gulp to build my angularjs application and want to somehow inject the latest git commit hash into my angular app so I can use it when debugging production issues.

Even if it is just a case of injecting it into my index.html template as a global variable that would be great.

Can anyone recommend a good technique and plugins to achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

I ended up using [git-rev-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-rev-sync) and [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) and put {{git}} in my index.html source file.

```
var git = require('git-rev-sync');

return gulp.src(pathConfig.src + 'index.html')
    .pipe($.replace('{{git}}', git.long()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(pathConfig.dest + 'index.html'));
```

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Answer (score 2):

> inject the latest git commit hash

Here is how you can do it:

git store the latest commit hash inside the `.git/refs/heads/<branch name>`.
Read this content of the file with the below code and then put it wherever you need

```
# load fs for reading /writing files
fs = require("fs"),

// define your task 
gulp.task('doSometing', function() {

  return gulp.src(dirs.src + '/templates/*.html')

    // read the  SHA-1 of the latest commit
    .pipe(fs.readFile("path/to/.git/refs/heads/<branch name>", 

          // Default encoding for fs is binary so we have to set it to UTF-8      
          "utf-8", 

          // Process the data you have read (SHA-1)
          function(err, _data) {
          //do something with your data
    })
   .pipe(gulp.dest('destination/path));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on the answer by @the-a-train for those not using jQuery.

```
var git = require('git-rev-sync');
var replace = require('git-replace');

return gulp.src(pathConfig.src + 'index.html')
  .pipe(replace('{{git}}', git.long()))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(pathConfig.dest + 'index.html'));
```